# How do I count how many double letters are in a string?

Tags: c#, string

Double Letters: A letter that appears consecutively twice. (Ex: "Google", "programming buddy")

Google contains 1 double letter. Programming buddy contains 2 double letters in the string.

Anyways here's my code

```
int doubleLetters = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < characters.Length - 1; i++)
{
    if (characters[i] == characters[i + 1])
    {
        doubleLetters++;
    }
}
```

The problem here is if a string was spelled "Gooogle" (3 O's), it would return me a count of 2 instead of 1. Basically, it would return me how many conesective letters - 1 as the result.

How do I make it so it would count the right amount of double letters? So if the string is  "looooool", it should give a 3. However, my code is counting this as 5 instead.

I'm trying to find code that can fix this.

Comment: So, should "Goooogle" return 2? In that case, you can just make the cursor jump ahead (i++) after a match.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    if (characters[i] == characters[i + 1])
    {
        doubleLetters++;
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Because of loop condition, you don't have to check anything before `i++`.

Comment: I'm gonna test this and hope it works. EDIT: Worked thanks a lot.